# How to install ffmpeg for android studio?

Tags: java, android-studio, ffmpeg, video-processing

Hi I'm trying to do a project in video processing. I want to demux and mux the videos from an mp4 container. I did it with MediaMuxer and all but now whenever i search everyone is recommending ffmpeg will be much easier. So I want to try this library. But for the life of me I can't figure out how to use this library. I want to integrate it with my current android studio project written in java. Some examples are given on how to install it in linux and some and are android ndk. Can anyone please guide me how to use this library. How to use and everything. I have read almost all the tutorials and still i'm not clear. Please. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Finally i found the answer.
For those who are on the same boat and haven't figured it out,

> First include this line into your build.grade module file:

```
 implementation 'com.arthenica:mobile-ffmpeg-full:4.3.1'
```

> Then import these methods:

```
import com.arthenica.mobileffmpeg.Config;
import com.arthenica.mobileffmpeg.FFmpeg;
import com.arthenica.mobileffmpeg.FFprobe;
```

and after this, when you are trying to execute the codes, use the commands without 'ffmpeg' on them. Reply if you still have doubts.